# Measuring Colloidal copper PPM & how to ignore the salt PPM in soluton

Tags: aqueous-solution

I made some colloidal copper with 9V battery. To make this water I had to add small amount of salt. However, the salt itself shows up in PPM count of my PPM reader. So how can I discount the salt PPM and come up with correct copper PPM in distilled water.

Answer (score -1):

First method is to look for Faraday's law of electrolysis and put in the equation your data.

Second method is to add to TDS reading the initial reading of the salt solution before the electrolysis.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). || Could you be a little bit more elaborate? With a link to Faraday's law of electrolysis, explaining the method more thoroughly etc. Right now, this isn't unfortunately a very good-quality answer according to chem.SE's standards.